# scala append to a mutable LinkedList

Tags: scala, collections, mutable

Please check this

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList

var l = new LinkedList[String]

l append LinkedList("abc", "asd")

println(l)
// prints 
// LinkedList()
```

but

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList

var l = new LinkedList[String]

l = LinkedList("x")
l append LinkedList("abc", "asd")

println(l)
// prints 
// LinkedList(x, abc, asd)
```

Why does the second code snippet works but the first one doesnt? This is on Scala 2.10

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The documentation says `If this is empty then it does nothing and returns that. Otherwise, appends that to this.`. That is exactly, what you observed. If you really need a mutable list, I would suggest you to use `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer` instead, with it you can do

```
val lb = new ListBuffer[Int]

scala> lb += 1
res14: lb.type = ListBuffer(1)

scala> lb
res15: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1)

scala> lb ++= Seq(1,2,3)
res17: lb.type = ListBuffer(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

scala> lb
res18: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: but why this behavior? why not append to self irrespective of the number of elements? isn't this is what is expected from a `mutable` collection?

Comment: Hinestly I don't have an idea. If you want to know the exact reason, you should try the official scala mailing list.

Comment: My guess would be that it's because it's much cheaper than actually modifying the list. Although, IMHO, that breaks the implied contract that mutation operations will in fact mutate the list.

Comment: `new LinkedList[String]` is not same as `LinkedList[String]()` isn't?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it is related to First/Last (`Nil`) element in the list (if list is empty `Nil` is first and last element at the same time).

LinkedList (still) follows "**[primitive charm](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList)**" strategy. So it does not try to add/append new data to/after `Nil`, to have possible result like this: {Nil, newElement}. (After all `Nil` should be last element)

Of course it could check `if` list is empty then put `addingList` to the beginning and `Nil` to the end. But this would be "too smart", I guess.

But, anyway `append()` returns "expecting" result Like this:

```
val addingList = new LinkedList[String]("a", "b")
val result = emptyList append addingList
```

`result = {"a", "b"}.` In this case it returns 'addingList' itself, and/but does not change initial list.

If we try to assign newElement to the `next` ref:

```
   emptyList.next = LinkedList("whatever")
```

As result we would have emtyList changed like this:

```
 LinkedList(null, whatever)
```

I.e. **it creates fist element as null**, since we have used `next()` assigning new/next element to it. So it moves Nil to the end, because first element which is null, has next reference to new element we added (`addingElelement`).

Because

> "the "emptyList" is also the "head" link"

and head in our case head is `Nil`, but `Nill` can not have next, so it has to create new first element (which is has null value) with next() referece to our new `addingElelement`.

Personally I find it "too much primitive" and not "so much elegant". But it depends, I guess.

**Task oriented story:**

For my initial task (why I start thinking about this 'strange' list behaviour [even though it's mutable]) -- I wanted to use mutable list for a class/object called `Dictionary` which would keep `Words` in it (dictionary by default has not any words). And I would have methods like a`ddWord(wod:String)` for adding new words. For now my implementation will be changed (I'm not going to use this `LinkedList`, but rather `MutableList`. It seems it is **more mutable** than previous one):

```
object Dictionary {

  val words = new mutable.MutableList[Word]();

  def addWord(word: Word): Unit = {
    words += word;
  }

}
```

**But possible implementation could be like this:**

```
object Dictionary {

  var words = new mutable.LinkedList[Word]();

  def addWord(word: Word): Unit = {

    if (words.isEmpty) {
      words = words append( mutable.LinkedList[Word](word) ) // rely on append result
    } else {
      words append( mutable.LinkedList[Word](word) )
    }

  }

}
```

But then I have to use `var` instead of `val`, and I should transform every new **Word** to `LinkedList`, and my logic became more complicated.